# Dataframe convert header row to row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

df:

```
165  156  1    test    greater 56gsa
-------------------------------------
spin 201  2    normal  lesser  12asgs
pine 202  3    fast    greater 5sasgs
```

required output:

```
0     1   2     3        4       5
-------------------------------------
165  156  1    test    greater 56gsa
spin 201  2    normal  lesser  12asgs
pine 202  3    fast    greater 5sasgs
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If DataFrame is created from file then `header=None` parameter is your friend:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
```

If not then convert column to one row `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original data:

```
df = df.columns.to_frame().T.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)
      0    1  2       3        4       5
0   165  156  1    test  greater   56gsa
1  spin  201  2  normal   lesser  12asgs
2  pine  202  3    fast  greater  5sasgs
```

Answer (score 12):

Try using `reset_index`:

```
print(df.T.reset_index().T)
```

For resetting and dropping original columns:

```
print(df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T)
```

Comment: nice. maybe you want to add `.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end to reset the new index?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
df.loc[len(df)] = df.columns
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
df
```